# How to interrupt a long running process - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have a GUI with a 'process' button. When the button is pressed, the following code is executed:

```
//Check for results truncation
boolean truncate = !jCheckBoxTruncate.isSelected();
String[] args = {fileName};
//run solution and draw graph
SpeciesSelection specSel = new SpeciesSelection(args, truncate);
Thread t = new Thread(specSel);
t.start();
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
cancelled = false;
jButtonCancel.setVisible(true);

new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (!specSel.isFinished() && !cancelled) {
       double seconds = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000.0;
       jLabelProcessTime.setText("Processing Time: " + toTimeString(seconds));
       try {
          Thread.sleep(91);
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(SpecSelGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }

jButtonCancel.setVisible(false);
jButtonProcess.setEnabled(true);
// If processing finished then display result graph, else the process was cancelled so stop the processing thread.
if (specSel.isFinished()) {
   ArrayList<Double> result = specSel.getResult();
   drawGraph(result);
}
else {
       t.interrupt();
     }
   }
}.start();
```

So I have a 'Thread t' that executes a long running process, and an anonymous thread that just updates the processing time on the GUI and monitors for a request to cancel Thread t. The SpeciesSelection class overrides run() as follows:

```
@Override
public void run() {
   long start = System.nanoTime();
   try {
       result = specSel(args, truncate);//VERY LONG RUNNING PROCESS CALLED ONCE
   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(SpeciesSelection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
   finished = true;
       System.out.println("Process took " + ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000.0) + "ms");
   }
```

I have a cancel button that sets the flag 'cancelled' to true. In the event that this button is pressed I attempt to interrupt Thread t. However, nothing happens and the thread continues to run. I think I'm missing something and would appreciate some help on how to properly interrupt the long running process/Thread t.

Comment: What type is the "cancelled" variable? If it is "boolean", make sure to declare it as "volatile boolean", so the information is seen by the other thread.

Comment: yes, its just boolean. Would you expect changing to volatile boolean to solve my problem? I tried that but it made no difference

Comment: I assume there is another problem. But if you use a shutdown flag that is shared between threads, without any synchronization there is no guarantee that the other thread will see the changes. Making the variable volatile is a simple way to do that, for instance: https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_typical_use.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I guess `specSel(args, truncate);//VERY LONG RUNNING PROCESS CALLED ONCE` doesn't support interruption.

For the interrupt mechanism to work correctly, the interrupted thread must support its own interruption.

How does a thread support its own interruption?

1. If the thread is frequently invoking methods that throw `InterruptedException`(like `Thread.sleep()`), you can handle the interrupt inside the ExceptionHandler like

   ```
   try {
      Thread.sleep(4000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // We've been interrupted: no more messages.
      return;
   }
   ```
2. What if a thread goes a long time without invoking a method that throws InterruptedException? Then it must periodically invoke Thread.interrupted, which returns true if an interrupt has been received. For example:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       if (Thread.interrupted()) {
           // We've been interrupted: no more crunching.
           return;
       }
   }
   ```

Since latter be the case of you, I suggest you do the second suggestion inside 
`specSel(args, truncate);` to support its interruption. Of course, you can do something else other than `return`. But this is what you wanted.